# Twig: Set default translation language

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

there is situation like this:

example.twig.html

```
<P>{%trans%}Example Message 1{%endtrans%}</P>
<P>{%trans%}Example Message 2{%endtrans%}</P>
<P>{%trans%}Example Message 3{%endtrans%}</P>
```

This is not template to show by visitor via web browser, but to send on mail

```
randomTroll@randomDomain.randomCountry
```

by Swift_Message.

I want to force change default laguage to Trollish, but I do not want to use this:

```
{%trans into 'trollish' %}...{% endtrans %}
```

every time. It works perfectly, but it is ugly like a troll after washing in swamp.

In controller i tried something like this before render('example.twig.html'):

```
$request->setLocale('trollish');
$this->get('session')->set('_locale', 'trollish');
```

then

```
{{ app.request.locale }}
```

returns  "trollish"

but used language in {% trans %}...{ %trans% } still is not trollish :(

How i can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, add:

```
$this->get('translator')->setLocale('trollish');
```